# Integrate the gaussian distribution PDF with limits [const,+inf) ?

Tags: gaussian

Hey all!

i want to find the integral pr = Integral(limits from a constant>0 to +infinite, and the function inside is the PDF of Gauss distribution)..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

in this link u can see the PDF function..

Does anyone knows how to do this?

thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an [elementary function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function).  But it can be done in terms of a special function known as the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)
$$
\mathrm{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-t^2} dt
$$

**edit Oct 28**

I mean this.  If
$$
f \bigl(x,\mu,\sigma^{2}\bigr) = \frac{\operatorname{e} ^{\frac{-(-x + \mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}
$$
then evaluate the quantity in your question in terms of erf as follows:
$$
\int_{c}^{\infty} f \bigl(x,\mu,\sigma^{2}\bigr) d x = \frac{1-\mathrm{erf} \biggl(\frac{(c - \mu)}{\sqrt{2}\; \sigma}\biggr)}{2}
$$

Comment: Thanks Gerald for your answer, but this erf(x) corresponds to what? you mean that i have to find the CDF?

I want the Integral{PDF, from known const to +inf}

the CDF i think finds the Integral{PDF, from -inf to zero}, right? 